# How to handle UISearchController while navigating to another view Controller in swift?

Tags: swift

I have a UISearchController in my view and another button,which on press navigates to another controller.The problem is if the search controller is focused ,On button click search controller just looses its focus for the first time.The user has to press the button once again to navigate to different view.But I want user to press the button once and navigate to other view.

```
    @IBAction func Logout(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("called");
    let firstPageView =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstView") as! ViewController
    self.presentViewController(firstPageView, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

The above function is not called.